# Save an attribute in a custom way in Ember-data

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, ember-data

Say that I have a model, which has some attributes which are stored in a database, and another one which is stored some place else, but the client receives it as a one single JSON blob.

```
App.Tournament = DS.Model.extend({
  name:              DS.attr("string"),
  ...
  is_registered:     DS.attr("boolean")
});
```

the attribut `is_registered` is not a part of the model in the server, and I would like to save it separately. Here's an example

```
tournament = App.store.find(App.Tournament, 1);
tournament.set("name", "foo bar");
tournament.set("is_registered", true);

App.store.commit();
```

and this would do something like

```
PUT /tournaments/1 name: "foo bar"
POST /tournaments/1/register
```

**or something like that, where an attribute is saved different than the default. Is there a simple way to do this, or am I approaching the problem in a wrong way?**

Answer (score 2):

I would manage this complexity on the server.  The problem with saving one logical item on the client in more than 1 request is that if one of the requests failed, your data might be corrupted.  If you do some sort of Facade service that coordinates what data goes where, you can wrap a transaction around the operation.